# How do we find integral closure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Find the integral closure of $\mathbb C[x^2,x^2-1] $ in $\mathbb C(x)$

I don't know much about integral closure,I've just learned about it.How do we find integral closure in practice ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\mathbb C[x^2,x^2-1]=\mathbb C[x^2]$. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: yeah I'm just trying some "random" examples,so how do we do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb C[x^2]\subset\mathbb C[x]$ is integral ($x$ is a root of $T^2-x^2\in\mathbb C[x^2][T]$), so the integral closure of $\mathbb C[x^2]$ in $\mathbb C(x)$ is $\mathbb C[x]$ since the last one is integrally closed.

Comment: Integrally closed because $\mathbb C[x]$ is a UFD,right?

Comment: Everything is clear now,thank you.